# Standard Protocols and Messaing standards for Financial Transaction?

Tags: transactions, jakarta-ee

I am trying to build a Payment gateway where other institutions will post transaction messages. I will have to process them. Processing is not a issue. Now what protocols standard should I use for keeping the gateway standard, to have a smooth integrations with other Financial Institutions.

I did a little research and decided to use Webservices with wsdl using JavaCFX. But each transaction will have so many parameters eg. 15. Having a function with so many parameters will be messy. So thought using ISO8583 messaging standard. So the webservice function will look like

> String postTransaction(String ISO_String)

The function will receive a serialised ISO 8583 Message as a string and return back a reply ISO 8583 message. Is this standard? Any Suggestions?

Comment: If you're going to be using ISO messages as parameters, what's the point in using a web service? It would be better to just implement asynchronous communication with ISO8583 messages.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment from Chochos says, WSDL should "describe" a webservice. A single `ISO_String` parameter is a very poor description of what the webservice requires an input. There is **no obvious benefit** (in fact, there is some overhead of) doing this the webservice way instead of asynchronous communication.